# Ignoring the first line of a csv file when sorting in Vim

Tags: sort, filetype-csv

I need to sort a csv file containing a header using Vim commands.

I currently have to following command (which uses the external sort):

```
:%!sort -t ',' -k9,9 -k8,8 -k10n -k2n -k3n -k4n -k5n -k6n -k7n
```

which works, but I need to be able to ignore the header line, which looks like this:

```
Customer Complaint,Date,City,State,Zip code,Solved
```

Is there any way to do this with Vim commands?

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
:2,$!sort -t ',' -k9,9 -k8,8 -k10n -k2n -k3n -k4n -k5n -k6n -k7n
```